# Multiple GTX 10xx No GPU devices in Cycles Compute Device

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I have 4 Geforce GTX 1080. 
Nvidia 378.66 driver
Windows 10 64bit. 
Blender v2.78b

Blender User Preferences -> System -> Cycles Compute Device -> None

Cycles render does not recognize my 4 Geforce GPU boards. I worked in previous Nvidia and Blender versions.

Therefore the GPU Compute under render settings is also grayed out.

[image]

I see that my original post has been marked as a duplicate but the solution to post [GPU compute grayed out](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73328/gpu-compute-greyed-out-for-gtx1070) is not applicable to mine.

I have no CUDA option in User Preferences -> System -> Cycles Compute Device
It says "None" there

[image]

Solutions?

Comment: Judging from the number of people asking the same thing, it looks to me like you are dealing with a bug. I do not know if is a blender issue or an Nvidia driver that is causing it. You might wan to report it see: [Best place to put bug reports?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73865/dual-gtx-1060-rendering-with-cycles

Comment: Probably since it worked in previous versions and nowbody has come up with a solution. I will to try to report it in even though I´ve never reported a bug before.

Comment: The problem is now analyzed. This problem accrues with the latest Nvidia 378.66 drivers for 64 bits, Windows 10 and Geforce 10 series. If I roll back to Nvidia 376.33 it works.

I don´t know who to report to. Nvidia or Blender or both?

Comment: Maybe the reason is that Blender doesn't sopport the card when it's in SLI Mode?